# How to implement for loop logic

Tags: php, logic

Is there a simple logic to implement for loop, demending on delimeter?

```
if $a>b for($i=a; $i>b; $i--)
else for($i=a; $i<b; $i++)
```

But I need it to be done in one loop I cant do something like

```
$start = $a<$b? $a : $b;
```

Because I need loop to always start with `$a` and go toward `$b`, maybe there another way?Can i have reason for downvoting? And what is unclear in my question, peoples if you dont understand question refrain from touching it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$inc = $a < $b ? 1: -1;
for ($i = $a; $i != $b; $i += $inc) {
    /* some code here */
}
```

Explanation:

First step is estimation of the increment meaning whether to increment or decrement $a to reach $b.

Obviously if $a < $b then increment needed or else decrement. $i += $inc is the generic statement that adds +1 or -1. Adding +1 is increment and adding -1 is decrement.

Ultimately the loop exit condition is $i != $b, hoping this condition will be met atleast once in the increment/decrement.

Comment: @SakthiKumar Do explain the code and the forloop...

Comment: @Mr. Alien nah, dont need, its simple.

Comment: @SakthiKumar perfect..

Comment: awesome answer, but kind of cryptic, an explanation would bring even more wonder

Comment: @Kuraiinazuma Well it may be simple for you but I didn't understood

Comment: First step is estimation of the increment meaning whether to increment or decrement `$a` to reach `$b`. Obviously if `$a < $b` then increment needed or else decrement. `$i += $inc` is the generic statement that adds `+1` or `-1`. Adding +1 is increment and adding -1 is decrement. Ultimately the loop exit condition is `$i != $b`, hoping this condition will be met atleast once in the increment/decrement. Hope you understand this @Mr.Alien

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ questions on SO is not just for OP, it is also for the visitors who end up searching for same issues, so there may be many who won't understand the code just like I didn't so editing the answer and sharing the explanation won't harm :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains some logical error. Although syntax is correct.

```
if $a<b for($i=a; $i>b; $i--)
```

Here, `$a` is smaller than `b` and in `for` loop you give condition `$i>b` which will never meet because `$i` and `$a` are already smaller than `b`. So, this loop will not run even for a single time. This is also same for `else` because here also loop will not execute for a single time.

Is that you want..?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you might have missed the green checklist under Sakthi's answer which means his answer is accepted. Please read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page for more...